# Linux core ids are missing in cpu info

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, cpu-architecture, boot, apic

I've a issue with am machine I'm running some paralell calculations on. 
Until now I assumed that core ids need to be sequentially. But on this machine I have:

```
lscpu
```

[image]

I get the following Output for:

```
/bin/cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'core id'
```

[image]

Since the code I'm using assumes that the number of cores is equal to `max(core ids) + 1`, this causes many problems. I can not change this assumption in the code easily. Therefore my questions are the following:

1. Are the core ids 5-7 just missing?
2. Or are these cores actually there but not "activated"?
3. Can I change this in a sense that I can rename the Ids?
4. Do I have something wrong in a sense that core Ids are never sequentially ordered?
5. What can cause such a unusual ordering?

Comment: The Q/A link you have cited is about process IDs, not processor or core IDs, which are completely different, so I've removed the link.

Comment: As far as I understand APIC, this standard doesn't require processor cores identifiers to be sequentially allocated. The standard requires only their uniqueness.

Comment: This may help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400605/understanding-core-ids

Comment: Are you running on a VM that doesn't pass through all the physical cores to your guest instance?

Comment: As far as I know it is not a VM. I checked with  'sudo virt-what' and got no return value which as far as I know means it is not a VM.